# How can I auto-assign a CPT post to category in a custom taxonomy when published?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I'm using the code below to auto-assign a CPT of 'item' to a category 'magazine', when the post is saved/updated.

```
function assign_item_category_automatically($post_ID) {

    global $wpdb;

    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, 'magazine', 'category');
    }
}

add_action('publish_item', 'assign_item_category_automatically');
```

It works fine, but the category to which it assigns is a normal category... whereas I want to assign it to a category in a custom taxonomy solely for the 'item' CPT - I don't want normal categories available to CPT posts, or custom taxonomies available to normal posts.

I have no idea how to modify this to do what I want.

Comment: there is not "normal" and "abnormal" categories. there is just a taxonomy named "category" and other taxonomies. then if you want another taxonomy, change the name "category" in `wp_set_object_terms(...`

Comment: I did a quick search and found https://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-category-to-a-custom-post-type-automatically

Comment: @bagpiper... Thanks. I'd seen that page but not understood enough until I read the answer from mmm and Krzysztof.

Answer (score 1):

As [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) says, `wp_set_object_terms` accepts 4 arguments:
`$object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append`

- `object_id` - ID of post, page, attachment or anything which is in post table
- `terms` - slug(s) or id(s) or term(s)
- `taxonomy` - slug of taxonomy - in your case it will be you custom taxonomy slug
- `append` - whether delete all existing terms assigned to object or append new on end

Usage: `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'magazine', 'your_taxonomy_slug', true);`

Comment: Thanks. I now understand this better. By not understanding what I was cut/pasting, I'd used 'category' instead of the taxonomy name.